# How do I solve this, The line $y= \frac{x}{k}+k$ is a tangent to the curve $4y=x^2$ at the point P.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

The line $y=\frac{x}{k}+k$ ,where k is a constant, is a tangent to the curve $4y=x^2$ at the point $P$. I have to find the value of k and the coordinates of $P$

I'm stuck and I don't what I'm doing wrong.To find K , I know I have to substitute , so I get

$4(\frac{x}{k}+k) =x^2$

$\frac{4x}{k}+k =x^2$

$4x+4k^2=x^2$

Then I  use the discriminant  $b^2 -4ac$ which gives
16 + 16k^2

$k^2 =-1$

I can't find $k$ because $k^2$ is negative

Answer (score 1):

Your fraction suddenly disappeared and you forgot the $4$. Your quadratic should be:
$$
4(\tfrac{x}{k}+k) =x^2 \implies \frac{4}{k}x + 4k = x^2 \implies x^2 - \frac{4}{k}x - 4k = 0
$$
Since the line is tangent, the system we are solving should have exactly one solution, so we know that the discriminant is zero. Thus:
\begin{align*}
0 = (-\tfrac{4}{k})^2 - 4(1)(-4k) = \frac{16}{k^2} + 16k
&\implies 16k = -\frac{16}{k^2} \\
&\implies k = \frac{-1}{k^2} \\
&\implies k^3 = -1 \\
&\implies k = -1
\end{align*}